# Are Firebase and Google Cloud free-usage quotas tied to different things? Projects or billing accounts?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I noticed that in the [GCP free tier documentation](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier) there is a line that says

> Free Tier resources are calculated per billing account.

The answer to the same question for Firebase isn't specified too explicitly in the Firebase Spark/Blaze plan documentation - but from my research, it *seems* as though it's calculated via project.

> In the image: "All projects in project one share the same free-usage quota. All projects in project two share the same free-usage quota" (both projects share the same billing account in the picture)

[image]

https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/billing/firebase-pricing-plans

It seems then that Firebase free-usage quotas are calculated **per project** while GCP usage is calculated **per billing account**.

If this is true, how does it work for example with, for example, Firestore? If I have two projects that are both Firebase and GCP on one billing account, GCP says I have 50,000 reads per month per billing account. Firebase says I have 50,000 reads per month per project. If each project does 50,000 reads, GCP (per billing account - 100,000 total) would charge me for the extra 50,000. But according to Firebase, it would fall under the free tier for each project (50,000 free each).

So what exactly determines whether to process free usage through GCP or Firebase? Is it determined via whether I started the project through Firebase or through Google Cloud? Or enabled Firestore through different pathways? How does it know which resource to associate with GCP (billing level) or Firebase (project level) to determine free-usage tier?

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised about that quote from the GCP docs, as in my experience there too the free quota/tier is applied to each project.

While I can't answer for all GCP products (there's just too many of them), I am certain that for any products that are shown on the Firebase [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) the free tier applies per project. So for GCP products that Firebase provides client-side SDKs for (like Firestore, Functions and Storage), the free quota is applied to each project.

---

This previous question seems to confirm my experience: [Google Cloud Tiered Billing - Project v Billing Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58440882/google-cloud-tiered-billing-project-v-billing-account)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the free quota only applies to the default database so if you are not using the default database in your projects, you will not benefit from the free quota for operations, storage and egress.

Comment: is this supposed to be a comment on the other answer?